# Virtualbox login lagging

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

So in our company we currently have a bunch of vms (virtualbox) setup in a gcp instance (specs below) but we are having a hell of lag on the login screen, what could possibly be? (tell me if you need more info).

Specs:
n1-highmem-32 (32 vCPUs, 208 GB memory)

Video of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM9aW.jpg

ThinkPinguin hardware test:
[hardware test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iXx4.png)

Comment: Did you enable nested virtualization? Why on earth are you using VirtualBox?!

Comment: Yes its enabled, its a legacy architecture, we didn't any time until now to explore a better tech for this tbh